# PyCharm launch via CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, path, pycharm

**Tech**: *Windows * CMD * PyCharm

**Desired Behavior**: I want to run `pycharm main.py`

**Error**:

> 'pycharm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

**What I've tried**:
I added `pycharm` to my `PATH`, restarted my computer

**Note**: When I run `echo %PATH%`, I can actually see that PyCharm is the last item of the path!

```
C:\Python39\Scripts\
C:\Python39\
C:\WINDOWS\system32
C:\WINDOWS
C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
C:\Program Files (x86)\Gpg4win\..\GnuPG\bin
C:\Program Files\dotnet\
C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin
C:\Program Files\nodejs\
C:\Users\some_user\anaconda3
C:\Users\some_user\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
C:\Users\some_user\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin
C:\Users\some_user\anaconda3\Library\bin
C:\Users\some_user\anaconda3\Scripts
C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14\bin
C:\Users\some_user\Apps\Microsoft VS Code\bin
C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Users\some_user\AppData\Roaming\npm
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm\bin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure, that the path to Pycharm is correct?
Did you navigate to `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm\bin` ?
In my case the path is as follows: `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1\bin`

To set the correct pat in Windows CMD you can do the following:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1\bin
```